# ScrollTo.js: scroll to the exact center of a div

Tags: jquery, centering, scrollto, gsap

I am trying to figure out the jquery to scroll the exact center of a div when you click a button. At present I can only scroll to the X and Y coordinate with a declared offset. This would mean I would have to redeclare the X and Y in jquery depending on what device you are using (large monitor, laptop, ipad, iphone), and it won't be exactly in the center either.

I know it has to do with declaring vars of window height and window width divided by 2 but am struggling to make it work using answers on SO.

```
var wWidth = $(window).width();
var wHeight = $(window).height();
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/artchibald/pen/ddKVNw

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about using half the width and height of the div. So it could become:

```
clickmeVar.onclick = function() {
TweenLite.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:{y:"#myDiv", offsetY: $(window).innerHeight() / 2 - $('#myDiv').height() / 2, x:"#myDiv", offsetX: $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - $('#myDiv').width() / 2, autoKill:false}},100);
};
```

Or without jQuery selectors:

```
clickmeVar.onclick = function() {
TweenLite.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:{y:"#myDiv", offsetY: window.innerHeight / 2 - document.querySelector('#myDiv').clientHeight / 2, x:"#myDiv", offsetX: window.innerWidth / 2 - document.querySelector('#myDiv').clientWidth / 2, autoKill:false}},100);
};
```

Here we're using half the visible screens width and height, minus half the width and height of the element.

Here's a working example:

```js
var clickmeVar = document.getElementById("clickme");
var windowheight = $(window).height();
var windowwidth = $(window).width();
var pagecenterW = windowwidth/2;
pagecenterW=pagecenterW/2;
var pagecenterH = windowheight/2;
pagecenterH=pagecenterH/2;

clickmeVar.onclick = function() {
TweenLite.to(window, 1, {scrollTo:{y:"#myDiv", offsetY: $(window).innerHeight() / 2 - $('#myDiv').height() / 2, x:"#myDiv", offsetX: $(window).innerWidth() / 2 - $('#myDiv').width() / 2, autoKill:false}},100);
};
//      $("#myDiv")
//      .css({top: pagecenterH + 'px', left: pagecenterW+ 'px'});
```

```css
body {
  width: 3000px;
  height:2000px;
  background:blue;
}
#myDiv {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  left:800px;
  top:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ScrollToPlugin-latest-beta.js"></script>

<button id="clickme">click here to put the red square exactly in the center of the viewport</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but unfortunately this places the red div in the center of the top left corner. I need the red square to be in the exact center of the whole view port. Even though the red square is not placed exactly at the center of the page.

Comment: @ArchieButler sorry for the confusion. I've updated my answer know to work how you want it to.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I have updated the codepen with the results. https://codepen.io/artchibald/pen/ddKVNw